# Relationship between Vin and Vout of a linear voltage regulator in saturation region

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, linear

Suppose we have a linear voltage regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA4SBg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If Vin is above Vth Vout is costant for all values Vin may take.However if Vin is below Vth what is the relationship between Vin and Vout?

Comment: Some data sheets from manufacturers recommends diode for protection IC, like 7805, in this situation. It may cause the damage

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the internal circuitry of the regulator. If the manufacturer doesn't provide this information then you should not make any assumptions, except that the regulator no longer regulates. One thing you can be sure of is that \$V_{out} \le V_{in}\$

Comment: Just observationally the difference is usually close to the rated dropout voltage.  I.e., if \$V_d\$ is the dropout voltage, then \$V_{out} \simeq V_{in} - V_d\$.  I'd trust this a lot more for input voltages just below what you need, and would expect it to not be true at all as the input voltage drops to well below the rated input.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** it depends

**Longer answer:**

We have to consider dynamic cases and static cases. For example, when the input voltage suddenly drops (and if there is a high capacity on the output side or really low load) the output can be higher than the input. You'll have to refer to the datasheet of your regulator (make and model) to see what it can handle and when it will break (you might need a reverse diode to protect your regulator if the possibility of Vout > Vin exists).

For a case where \$V_{in} < V_{out} + V_{th}\$ you'll have to refer to the datasheet again. Keep in mind, that you can get parts with the same number from different manufacturers. The internals of an 7805 from one manufacturer do not have to be the same as the 7805 of another one. So different things can happen.

- \$V_{out} = V_{in} - V_{th}\$ with no regulation
- \$V_{out} = V_{in} - V_{min}\$ (and \$V_{min}\$ can be \$< V_{th}\$)

Generaly: don't run components for prolonged times outside specs. Wierd things can happen there.

Answer (score 1):

I've put a three-terminal regulator on a curve tracer,
basically running a ramp voltage in, and seen the voltage
on a load resistor on the output.  The old uA7805
just tracked the input voltage when input was in the
below-five-volts-out range, until about 2V input,
where apparently internal current sources lost bias.

Other designs may vary, but few such regulators
have any low-input-voltage shutoff thresholds, they
just keep on conducting.   Not regulating, just
conducting.

With negative bias, but no capacitance on the output pin,
the uA7805 had diode-like conduction to input from
common.   As far as I can tell, small reverse currents
didn't hurt the device.   It is said that large
output filter capacitors and low input voltage CAN
burn the chip up, and a protective diode is recommended  if 1000 uF is on the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rely on the data sheet. Some manufacturers provide schematics, but none of them claim that they are good for analyzing performance outside of recommended operating conditions: they're just to aid understanding how the part works. If you find a part that does have detailed performance data you can't depend on another part, from someone else, with the same generic number (like 7805) performing the same. If you test a part and find it meets your needs beyond the published specifications, you can't even assume that other parts from the same manufacturer also will. A later production run can be lots different. The only thing that counts is the data sheet.